# HTML Table doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I use this code

[image]

and obtain this result

[image]

I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: What is your problem...?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Whats the problem? What do you want to do? what is not working? whats the answer to life the universe and everything???

Comment: height atribute does not work

Comment: The parent element (body/table) doesn't have a height specified. so it can't calculate 80% of it. But I'm sure someone else can explain better.

Comment: Try using px and not %.  For ex: 10px or 20px.  Bootstrap uses "padding:8px;" here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/.  Use chrome to change the css in-line until it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, the height is your problem, you have to set the height of the parent container as well, try setting the html and body heights to 100%:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks, now works, but, I watched the tutorial with identical code and get different results but I do not know why ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I have another question, how does 'width' attribute if not listed as 'html, body {width: 100%}'?